# Wpf data binding to an object's properties property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So I know there is lots of databinding response but I couldn't find what I was looking for. Or I couldn't make it work correctly.

In my case, I have an class which has two properties type FootScan like this :

```
public class ScanResult
{
    public FootScan LeftFoot { get; set; }
    public FootScan RightFoot { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class FootScan
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    public double FootLength { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

In my window, I have this:

```
    public ScanResult CurrentScan
    {
        get { return (ScanResult)this.GetValue(CurrentScanProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CurrentScanProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentScanProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "CurrentScan", typeof(ScanResult), typeof(wndScanner), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

And On Window_Loaded:

```
      CurrentScan = new ScanResult();
      CurrentScan.LeftFoot = new FootScan();
      CurrentScan.LeftFoot.FootLength = 285; //Normally comes from the scan result.
```

And the XAML side I want to bind the text property of my textblock to CurrentScan.LeftFoot.FootLength:

And I tried :

```
1-  <TextBlock x:Name="tbFootLength" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CurrentScan.LeftFoot.FootLength}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="15"/>
        


2-  <Grid x:Name="grdMeasures" DataContext="{Binding CurrentScan}" Margin="0,35,0,256" Background="#FFE7E7F3">

     <TextBlock x:Name="tbFootLength" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LeftFoot.FootLength}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="15"/>
   
    </Grid>       


3-   <Grid x:Name="grdMeasures" DataContext="{Binding CurrentScan.LeftFoot}" Margin="0,35,0,256" Background="#FFE7E7F3">

     <TextBlock x:Name="tbFootLength" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FootLength}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="15"/>
   
    </Grid>
```

Any idea pleas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `CurrentScan` defined? In the same window as the `TextBlock`?

Comment: `Text="{Binding CurrentScan.LeftFoot.FootLength}"` should work, provided you have set the Window's DataContext to itself, e.g. by `DataContext = this;` in its constructor.

Comment: mm8, I edited the question, I added the initialisation part of the CurrentScan.

Comment: @CoskunOzogul: Try to set the source of the binding then. See my answer.

Comment: I try these solutions

Comment: This is not a dupplicate of the recommended question. Not the same thing.

Comment: It doesn't matter if there is a simple or complex property path. Your problem is that you did not set the source of the Binding.

Comment: Finally, it doesn't work, I tried all. I probably skip something.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

If `CurrentScan` is a property of the window in which the `TextBlock` is defined, this binding should work:

```
Text="{Binding CurrentScan.LeftFoot.FootLength, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Don't forget to initialize the `CurrentScan` property, i.e. set it.

Comment: It doesn't work mm8, I think I missed something somewhere.

Comment: Is the `TextBlock` in the window? Please post your full code.

Comment: It worked like this:  DataContext = this;  on load. And in xaml Text="{Binding ElementName=mw, Path=CurrentScan.LeftFoot.FootLength}". Thanks for help.

Comment: You don't need `DataContext = this` if you bind to an `ElementName` or a `RelativeSource`.